# Android Retrofit2 passing an unknown generic class

Tags: java, android, class, generics, retrofit2

I am trying to write a retrofit helper class, so when doing so I need to keep everything a generic as possible.

I am writing a method that creates an API call the is supposed to return a list of a class. Because it is a helper class, the type of class is determined at runtime, and I need to create a method to receive a Generic class.
When trying to do so, I used the code:

**Client interface:**

```
 public interface Client{  
   @GET("{endpoint}")
   Call<List<Class<T>>> createGetRequestReturnTypeList(@Path("endpoint") String endPoint);
 }
```

**Helper method:**

```
public void createGetRequest(Class<T> tClass, String endPoint) {
  mClient = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("baseUrl").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(Client.class);  

  Call<List<tClass>> call = mClient.createGetRequestReturnType(endPoint);

  call.enqueue(new Callback<List<tClass>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Response<List<GithubRepo>> response) {

      if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        List<tClass> class= response.body();
      } else {
        // The sever error code
        switch (response.code()) {
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<GithubRepo>> call, Throwable t) {
    }
  });
}
```

When writing the following methods, the T in `Class<T>` cannot be resolved.
Can someone please explain to me why, and how can I achieve being able to pass a generic class as a parameter?

Thank you

Comment: Yes... so just pass the generic an object?

Comment: Do you really need to use Generics?

Comment: Becuase it's a helper class, The Class/Object that is returned cannot be determined, so yeah...

Comment: Tried using an Object, the compiler says that the object in `Call<List<object>>` is an unknown class...

Comment: I don't think so since the Object, is the passed as a parameter in the method...
`public void createGetRequest(Object object){ 
//...}`

Comment: I think this post is similar to what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706275/retrofit-generic-reponse-handler

Comment: you must introduce the generic type with `<T>` before you can actually use it